# How to empty date range when radio button is selected

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datepicker, jquery-3

I've problem to empty date range when radio button is selected on modal bootstrap 4

This is the code HTML:

```html
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Island A Kanan</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="r1cian" value="0" id="r1cian" checked="checked">Normal
            <input type="radio" name="r1cian" value="1" id="r2cian" > Abnormal
        </div>
        <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div  class="form-group row " id="tglan">
    <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label">Date Range</label>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <div class="input-daterange input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control-sm form-control" name="tglscian" id="tgl" placeholder="Start Date" readonly>
            <div class="input-group-addon">to</div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control-sm form-control" name="tglecian" id="tgl" placeholder="End Date" readonly>
        </div>
        <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the code Ajax/JS:

```js
success: function(data)
    {
        if (data.stsAkn == "0") {
            $('#r1cian').prop('checked', true)
            $('#tgl').datepicker('update', '');
            $("#tglan").hide();

        } else if (data.stsAkn == "1") {
            $('#r2cian').prop('checked', true)
            $("#tglan").show();
            $('[name="tglscian"]').val(data.stglAkn);
            $('[name="tglecian"]').val(data.etglAkn);
        } 
     }
```

I've tried

1. `$('#tgl').datepicker('update', '');`
2. `$('[name="tglscian"]').datepicker('update', '');`
3. `$('[name="tglecian"]').datepicker('update', '');`
4. `$('#tgl').val('');`

But still can't empty the date,
what's solution for this?

I use bootstrap datepicker 
https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: try $('[name="tglscian"]').datepicker('setDate', null);

Comment: @Saeed I've tried $('[name="tglscian"]').datepicker('setDate', null); and $('#tgl').datepicker('setDate', null); but still not work there's another solution?

Comment: Do you have an online demo?

Comment: I don't have @Saeed what should i do again for solve this?

Comment: try this also $('#tgl').datepicker(); $('#tgl').val('');

Comment: i've tried both but date range can't empty when radio button is selected on modal bootstrap 4 @Saeed

Comment: These methods work on demo page https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/ . Without a minimum working demo, it is not easy to help.